# Protect from Facebook like clickjack

Tags: facebook, clickjacking

In the past month I've seen a better grade growth in sites that have clickjacking scripts that make you like the webpage or the Facebook site's Page when you click anywhere on the page. I have even seen sites that have this for "on Page close".

I am curious if there is a way to protect myself from such scams. Turning JS off is not a solution or stay logged out of Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at **[NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/noscript/)**. Obviously its main purpose is to deactivate JavaScript (and other "add-ons" to your browser) globally and activate it only for selected (i.e. trusted) sites. Nevertheless **it can be operated differently**, e.g. you can **leave JavaScript activated, while still profiting from other security mechanisms, e.g. its [ClearClick](http://noscript.net/faq#clearclick) technology**, which exactly addresses your concerns.

Refer to the [appropriate FAQ section](http://noscript.net/faq#faqsec7) for details on what this protects you against and how it works. The FAQ also states that you are pretty much out of luck, when not using Firefox. I'm not sure whether this is an overstatement, but at least I'm not aware of any alternatives.